# One-Class SVM: Precision, recall, and F1

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, anomaly-detection

I have a question

I have written the code below by using *sklearn*

```
self.model = SVM.OneClassSVM(gamma='scale', kernel='rbf').fit(training_set)
classification_report(self.ground_truth_label, self.predicted_results, target_names=target_names)
```

However, this picture below shows f1 score (Macro) is not located between precision and recall

I know *f1 = (2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall)*

Why...?

Thank you for your explanation !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro average `f1-score` given by `classification_report` is the unweighted average of the f1-scores for the two classes in your dataset, i.e.

`(0.12 + 0.67) / 2 ≈ 0.40`

It is not, as you might have thought, the f1-score computed with the macro averages of precision and recall.

---

To put it in another way:

it is **the average of all `f1-scores`**

and

it is ***not* the `f1-score` of the (precision and recall) averages**

Comment: So, do you mean I should check weighted avg part?

Comment: otherwise, does general f1 mean (macro avg + weighted avg) / 2 ??

Comment: @Dae-YoungPark what is a "general" f1-score? The f1-scores are calculated separately for each class and then averaged. `classification_report` already gives you all relevant types of averages. With `macro`, the average is not weighted (as in the answer). With `weighted`, the scores are additionally weighted by support to account for class imbalance.  Check the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#from-binary-to-multiclass-and-multilabel) for better understanding. But all of them will not consider the averages of precision or recall.